# Is there a built in way to group Bootstrap classes into "meta classes"?

Tags: class, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to twitter-**bootstrap**, and this question is probably answered 1000 times - I can't find proper search terms.

If I want to repeat the same group-of-classes on multiple elements, how can I tell bootstrap to apply all classes in that group onto certain elements?

e.g. (pseudo-code)

```
animal: {col-zz-5 tip tralala trili li kuki top-margin-20 lorem ipsum}

<li meta-class="animal">gamal</li>
<li meta-class="animal">soos</li>
<li meta-class="animal">kipod</li>
```

and NOT:

```
<li meta-class="col-zz-5 tip tralala trili li kuki top-margin-20 lorem ipsum">gamal</li>
<li meta-class="col-zz-5 tip tralala trili li kuki top-margin-20 lorem ipsum">soos</li>
<li meta-class="col-zz-5 tip tralala trili li kuki top-margin-20 lorem ipsum">kipod</li>
```

constraints:

I REALLY prefer not to add external solution like LESS, which adds another level of complication (learning, loading, performance and maintenance).

I don't want to do that on the server.

BTW: my current projects are based on **angular** - so if there's a built-in angular solution, this is also accepted.  E.g. I can write my classes as class="{{ animal }}", and define "animal" somewhere central (where?)

**Edit:**

I forked @NeilKistner 's fiddler => with a working solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/qaZmF/

hope to hear more solutions before I close this one.

Comment: Not really, the idea is that classes are `reusable`. What happens if you want to remove `lorem` and `ipsum` classes from the last element, or a random element.

Comment: @nickR - my question is for cases where I DO want all these classes together.

Answer (score 1):

Using AngularJS I was able to come up with this, you should be able to adapt it to your project.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <li meta-class="{{ animal }}">gamal</li>
      <li meta-class="{{ animal }}">soos</li>
      <li meta-class="{{ animal }}">kipod</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.animal = 'col-zz-5 tip tralala trili li kuki top-margin-20 lorem ipsum';
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2c24r/